# CAST() not changing to datetime format

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq, datetime, casting

I am using this SQL query to convert my `_Submission_date` column which of type `nvarchar(max)` to `datetime` format:

```
SELECT
    CAST(PSCData._SUBMISSION_DATE AS DATETIME2)
FROM 
    PSCData
```

I have tried every possible way but still its giving this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The data inside my `_Submission_Date` is in this form:

```
"2017-8-21 21:13:55.00000"
"2017-9-21 14:13:55.00000"
```

When I run this query it works fine:

```
SELECT CAST('2017-08-25' AS DATETIME);
```

but with this format :

```
SELECT CAST('2017-9-21 14:13:55.00000' AS DATETIME);
```

I get the same error mentioned above.

Any suggestions that how I can solve this?

Comment: You obviously have some value in there that isn't a valid datetime2 string.

Comment: yes the data is in this format "2017-8-21 21:13:55.00000" i have found out that the .00000 in the end is the actual cause of the problem.can u tell what to do in this situation?

Comment: i have edited the question as well

Comment: I now see in your examples below the query you are testing with `datetime`, not with `datetime2`. That is a difference as your sample will work with `datetime2` just fine (try it). It is probably another value that is causing the issue. `SELECT CAST('2017-8-21 21:13:55.00000' AS DATETIME2)` works fine, you have values that do not conform as already stated by @SadiaRashid.

Comment: it doesnt matter it gives the error in both situation.as i have said the main problem is ".00000" at the end. i have identified it

Comment: `datetime2` as you have it will allow up to 9 `0` characters at the end. Try `SELECT CAST('2017-8-21 21:13:55.000000000' AS DATETIME2)`. How many do you have in your data?

Comment: tried it like this but not working :select CAST(PSCData._SUBMISSION_DATE as DATETIME2)
FROM PSCData

Comment: i have 5 "0" at the end

Comment: That is acceptable, you have an outlier somewhere.

Comment: then it might be the  commas that are creating the problem the data is in this form "2017-8-21 21:13:55.00000"

Comment: try to run this query it will not work : SELECT CAST( ' "2017-8-21 21:13:55.000000000" ' AS DATETIME2)

Comment: No, of course that would not work. You have spaces and double quotes inside your string...

Comment: To be clear, does your datetime string include double quotes, or are you using those to qualify it as a string?

Comment: Please tell me that part of your project is to convert to a datetime datatype so you can obliterate storing dates as strings and this problem will forever be dealt with. If that isn't part of your project you are fighting a battle that you are going to keep fighting over and over and over....

Comment: i can do nothing with the data as it is uploading from a live link and it is storing date in a string format.i have no access to the data to change it that is the main problem...

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The actual problem was the double quotes around the string which was causing the error it can be solved like this:

```
update PscData
SET _SUBMISSION_DATE = REPLACE(_SUBMISSION_DATE,'"', '')

select CAST(PSCData._SUBMISSION_DATE as DATETIME2)
FROM PSCData
```

i.e: first use the REPLACE method to remove double quotes around the string than you can use the cast method and can easily convert the "varchar" type data to "datetime" format without any problem. Plus u have to use "datetime2" in the cast method as "datetime" will not work with it.
Thanks for the help btw :)